# Properties of Euler Class

Tags: characteristic-classes, orientation

I am reading Milnor & Stasheff's Characteristic classes (page 98 to be precise). After defining the Euler class, they state two basic properties claiming that the proofs are obvious:

> 1.(Naturality). If $f: B \to B'$ is covered by an
> orientation preserving bundle map $\xi\to\xi'$, then $e(\xi)=f^*e(\xi')$

> 2.If the orientation of $\xi$ is reversed, then the
> Euler class $e(\xi)$ changes sign.

I think for the first one we need to check the definition for $e(\xi)$ is staistied for  $f^*e(\xi')$. But I'm not sure how to proceed. In the second I don't know how to reverse orientation for a bundle.

Kindly Help!!

Any kind of Hint will be really helpful.

Regards

Comment: Reversing the orientation changes the sign of the Thom class, hence of the Euler class

Comment: @ThePuix thank you for comment although the text mentioned above doesnot define Thom Class I am suspecting it is the image of Thom isomorphism But i am afraid they don't use that to define Euler class

Comment: They do, look at theorem 9.1 and the definition of the Euler class, even though it is a little differently stated. The wiki article gives an explicit formula in terms of the Thom class.

Comment: @ThePuix I think I may have misunderstood, So they define the fundamental cohomology class in thm 9.1 after that they are giving the Thom isomorphism and then they are defining the Euler class . But where exactly are they are using Thom I can only see the fundamental class.

Comment: Yes, that is a little confusing: The Thom class *is* the fundamental class

Comment: oh.. then it is fyn, can u give any thoughts about the first one? @ThePuix

Comment: This should really just be unpacking definitions: The Thom class is the unique class restricting to a generator in each fiber. As the bundle map covers, it induces a (natural) isomorphism on the fibers. Then naturality of cup products and so on gurantees that pulling back the Thom class on one bundle defines a Thom class for the other one, hence they must be equal by uniquness.